# Volume shader with noise texture

Tags: shaders

[image]  I tried to make elephant paste in fluid and used Principled volume shader and gave color using noise texture with color ramp but the problem is texture stay still and not moving with mesh deformation.
tried various texture coordinates like generated, object, UV but texture stay still
its just stay still like connected to camera or window coordinates in normal material.
Does anyone no the solution ?.

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand, can you show some screenshots?

Comment: fluids moves but noise texture stay like stuck to the camera

Comment: Maybe switch the Noise to 4D and animate its Z value so that it changes through time?

Comment: If you want your texture to flow together with the fluid, you can't achieve it through a noise texture in shader. Instead you need to make your shader be very susceptible to density changes, and have the fluid vary in density, have some air pockets etc. I'm not into fluid simulations so I don't know how much of that can be achieved in the sim…

Comment: @moonboots i tried to animate texture, its not perfect but its works since fluid move very fast, thanks

Comment: Yes in your case the texture can't really follow the fluid as it separates in several branches so I guess you need to use a trick